# html-agility-pack extract a background image

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

How do I extract the url from the following HTML.

i.e.. extract:

```
http://media.somesite.com.au/img-101x76.jpg
```

from:

```
<div class="media-img">
    <div class=" searched-img" style="background-image: url(http://media.somesite.com.au/img-101x76.jpg);"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XPath 1.0 in general, you can use combination of `substring-after()` and `substring-before()` functions to extract part of a text. But HAP's `SelectNodes()` and `SelectSingleNode()` can't return other than node(s), so those XPath functions won't help.

One possible approach is to get the entire value of `style` attribute using XPath & HAP, then process the value further from .NET, using regex for example :

```cs
var html = @"<div class='media-img'>
    <div class=' searched-img' style='background-image: url(http://media.somesite.com.au/img-101x76.jpg);'></div>
</div>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class,'searched-img')]");
var url = Regex.Match(div.GetAttributeValue("style", ""), @"(?<=url\()(.*)(?=\))").Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(url);
```

**<kbd>[.NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W2IWCa)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
http://media.somesite.com.au/img-101x76.jpg
```

Comment: Hey, nice work! I was getting nothing at all without the Regex. It was all a little confusing. Thanks..